# CSV or DB is quicker to read several lines from a file with 1,5 billion lines

Tags: postgresql, performance, db2, csv

I have a program which would read several lines according to the indices of lines within a CSV file with 1,5 billion lines(using c `fgets`, or is there any tool in C faster than `fgets`?). Compare with storing records into a DB (postgesql or any other) table then reads the ID without any join, would the first propose the better way to do it?

Comment: A well-written, custom-written C program should always be faster than a database, as long as it incorporates the same performance features the database does, like appropriate indexes, and without the overhead of ACID.  But writing excellent C code takes a long time.

Comment: Great. Instead of looking for "...any tool in C...", custom written C code can do wonders. @jjanes please make it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two great and very fast tools for structured text files are:

- xsv https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv
- tsv-utils https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils